# how to view List<Image>?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm converting the files I receive from my API as Images and add it to my `List<Image> imageList`;

How can I then show it using `Listview.builder`?

I tried using

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: imageList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Image.memory(imageList[index].getBytes());
                });
```

but it returns an error

```
Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.
```

Are there other ways? Thanks for those who can help.

Comment: what is `Image` in  `List<Image>` ? note: flutter has 3 different `Image` classes

Comment: as I hover, it says "an image buffer where pixels are encoded into 32-bit unsigned ints (Uint32)"

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Encoder/encodeImage.html but its easier to use https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/encodePng.html for example (or any other `encode*` function)

Comment: sorry for being ignorant but as I followed the function on encodePng.html,
PngEncoder is undefined.

Comment: hmmm, what you mean by that? maybe https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/encodeJpg.html is better in your case? what kind of images do you get? "normal" images taken by camera (jpgs)?

Comment: I've got it! thanks for this!  I've assigned the Image class as "im". that's why I can't find the "PngEncoder" function.

Comment: your welcome, but again, maybe `encodeJpeg` is better? check the length of returned lists for both functions

Comment: yes, I used encodeJpg. =)